# jQuery function doesn't return anything on callback

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a jQuery function that takes the selected option of a form select element and sends it to a php file, which is supposed to return the html to populate a second select element.  Unfortunately, the jQuery is firing, but the return is empty.  Any ideas?

Form elements:

```
if ($result) {

            echo '<label>*Team: <select name="team" class="team" style=\'width: 150; font-size: 16px;\' autocomplete="off" tabindex="1">';
            echo '<option value="">Select</option>';

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['TeamID'].'">'.$row['CaptainLast']."  ".date('m-y',strtotime($row['ArrDate'])).'</option>';
            }

            echo '</select></label>';

} else {
            echo "0 results";
}


?>

<label>*Team Member: <select name="member" class="member" style='width: 150; font-size: 16px;' autocomplete="off" tabindex="2">
<option value="">Select</option>
</select></label>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change','.team', function(){
      var id=$(".team option:selected").val();
      var dataString = 'tmid='+ id;
      console.log(dataString);

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "scripts/memfltpop.php",
         data: dataString,
         dataType: 'html',
         success: function(html){
             $(".member").html(html);
         } 
      });

    });
});
```

and the server file:

```
<?php
$team = $_POST['tmid'];
echo $team;
$con = mysqli_connect('**********', '****', '******', '*******');

if ($con) {
        $sql = "SELECT MemberAdmin.IndID, MemberAdmin.First, MemberAdmin.Last ". "FROM MemberAdmin ". "LEFT JOIN Members ON MemberAdmin.IndID = Members.IndID ". "WHERE Members.TeamID='" .$team. "'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

        if ($result) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $id=$row['IndID'];
                $data=$row['First']." ".$row['Last'];
                echo '<option value="">Select</option>';
                echo '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$data.'</option>';

            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }
        }
        else {
            echo'Not connected to database';
        }
```

Comment: You need to use echo not console.log...

Comment: This won't run. You can't use `console.log` in PHP. That's javascript.

Comment: Ok, moved console.log() to jQuery, good console return, but echo still not returning anything from server script.

Answer (score 1):

For getting response in html, you need to use dataType html inside ajax request like this :

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "scripts/memfltpop.php",
     data: dataString,
     dataType : 'html',
     success: function(html){
         $(".member").html(html);
     } 
  });
```

Comment: Tried it, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, found it.  I never thought this would cause the SQL to freak out, but I changed from

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
```

to

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
```

As I was updating my SQL language, I missed this line.  Thanks guys!